# Create empty enumeration of given Type

Tags: c#

I have a given type:

```
Type modelType = context.ModelType;
```

How can I create an Enumeration of that type?

The best I was able to do was create an enumeration of object and use it:

```
IEnumerable<Object> numbers = Enumerable.Empty<Object>();
```

So what I need is something like this (nonworking code):

```
// Doesn't compile, since modelType is a variable and not the actual type
IEnumerable<Object> numbers = Enumerable.Empty<modelType>();
```

Comment: `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Empty").MakeGenericMethod(modelType).Invoke(null, null)` would do. It irks me that we need reflection, though. `Array.CreateInstance(modelType, 0)` does not, but won't cache the objects.

Comment: this could answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/9860408/2630427

Comment: I would have used `new T[] {}`. But now that I've read your question I'll probably use `Enumerable.Empty<T>` instead. This is a rarity, to me at least. You seem to be asking for a better way to do something, but you're actually showing a better way than what at least some of us (such as me) would have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Instances of Types using the [Activator Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=netframework-4.8). You then just need to supply the correct type information.

You can then cast the instance to any Type that is suitable for every `modelType` supplied.

```
var modelType = typeof(Int32); // Or whatever type you enter
var listOfModelType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(modelType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfModelType);
var isListInt = instance is List<Int32>; // Will evaluate to true
```

You could also make a static method for this.

```
    public static object GetEmptyEnumerableOfType(this Type type)
    {
        var listOfModelType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfModelType);
        return instance;
    }
```

Call it like that:

```
        var modelType = typeof(Int32);
        var emptyList = modelType.GetEmptyEnumerableOfType();
```

The only problem is, that you cant cast it into `IEnumerable<object>` since in this case it is a `struct`. If you can ensure its only called for types derived from `class` you could create the following overload:

```
    public static IEnumerable<object> GetEmptyEnumerableOfClass(this Type type)
    {
        return (IEnumerable<object>) type.GetEmptyEnumerableOfType();
    }
```

But it will throw an exception if called with a struct.

Comment: That was not the question ... I would like to create an empty Enumerable of modelType. Consider modelType is Int32 I would like to create a Enumerable of Int32

Comment: ah well one moment

Comment: Looks like OP needs variable T .

Comment: Im ajusting the answer just have a sec pls

Comment: Type is unkown. No way to cast it to List<int> or anyother type. If Op knew the type he/she could do already do Enumerable.Empty<int>()

Comment: @ÖzgürKaplan I know, he can supply any type as Model Type.